# SQL, procedimiento o consulta para ordenar lista de consecutivos

Tags: sql-server, lista, sql

tengo una tabla en la cual cada elemento tiene un campo de posición de 1 a 12, pero necesito una consulta que al cambiar la posición de uno de estos elementos, los demás elementos se reacomoden.
Es decir digamos que tengo un elemento en la posición 5 y le asigno que sea ahora 2, por lo tanto la que estaba en 2 se deberá correr hacia adelante osea a la 3, y la 3 a la 4 y así sucesivamente.
No he podido dar con el chiste en SQL, agradezco su valiosa ayuda.

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Es que esto no se resuelve en sql, se resuelve con un proceso ;).. mira por favor [ask], y agrega todo lo que intentaste y un ejemplo bien claro

Answer (score 0):

Se supone que el 1005 sería el ID para cambiar el orden:

```
UPDATE table1 SET orden = 2 WHERE id = "1005";
```

Luego debemos actualizar con tomando el orden y incrementar todos los registros:

```
SET @ordenNuevo = 2;

UPDATE table1 SET orden = @ordenNuevo := @ordenNuevo + 1 WHERE orden > 2;
```

Comment: La variable sobra ;)

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi

Comment: El problema es que ya existe un `orden = 2`,  deberías incrementar los valores en primer lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí dejo una solución que permite actualizar dependiendo de si el valor cambia hacia arriba o hacia abajo. Recalcula todos los valores de la tabla (se pueden limitar por grupo) cambiando la posicion original por la nueva con un valor inferior o superior dependiendo de como sea el cambio.

```
DECLARE @PosicionOriginal int = 2,
        @PosicionNueva    int = 6;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN @PosicionOriginal > @PosicionNueva
                                        THEN ISNULL( NULLIF( Posicion, @PosicionOriginal), @PosicionNueva-.1)
                                        ELSE ISNULL( NULLIF( Posicion, @PosicionOriginal), @PosicionNueva+.1) END) AS nueva_posicion
    FROM Ejemplo
)
UPDATE CTE
SET posicion = nueva_posicion;
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de lograr tu objetivo usando cte como tabla temporal en memoria. No sé muy bien como tienes pensado solucionar cuando la posición "desde" sea mayor que la posición "hacia".

```
declare @from int = 2
declare @to int = 5

;with data as (
  select 1 as id, 3 as posicion union all
  select 2 as id, 1 as posicion union all
  select 3 as id, 6 as posicion union all
  select 4 as id, 2 as posicion union all
  select 5 as id, 7 as posicion union all
  select 6 as id, 4 as posicion union all
  select 7 as id, 5 as posicion 
),
cte as (
  select d.* 
  from data d
  where d.posicion >= @from
    and d.posicion <= @to
)
select d.id, case when d.posicion=@to then @from else isnull(c.posicion+1,d.posicion) end as posicion
from data d
  left join cte c
    on d.posicion=c.posicion
```